# Passin SSRS parameters or dataset count to vb code?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I'm working in SSRS and have succeeded in creating a 5 tier cascaded parameter set up. Now I'm trying to say that if ALL is selected on tier 2 then filter the dataset differently than of single select.

TO do that I need count of selected and count of all and am trying to write some vb code in ssrs to fix this.

Pasted in this from microsoft

```
Public Function ShowParameterValues(ByVal parameter as Parameter)
 as String
   Dim s as String 
   If parameter.IsMultiValue then
      s = "Multivalue: " 
      For i as integer = 0 to parameter.Count-1
         s = s + CStr(parameter.Value(i)) + " " 
      Next
   Else
      s = "Single value: " + CStr(parameter.Value)
   End If
   Return s
End Function
```

But get error message:
The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox4.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: [BC30451] 'ShowParameterValues' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

So 2 questions - 1 how do I declare it and what do I pass in? Options Are

1. Report.Parameters!Company
2. Parameters!Company
3. Parameters!Company.Value

Any help greatly appreciated

Pete

Comment: Thanks for help here. I worked around my issue by putting a 6th cascaded parameter into the report, managing a null issue en route. But still useful learning. Thanks Alan

Answer (score 0):

Two things here...

To solve your error, make sure you call the function in the expression like this

```
=Code.<myFunctionName>(parameters)
```

So in your case it would probably be

```
=Code.ShowParameterValues(Parameters!Company)
```

(you might need to use `Parameters!Company.Value`, I can't remember)

However, you said you wanted to just know if a single value multiple values have been selected. You can do this without custom code.

```
=Parameters!Company.Length
```

Will return the number of selected parameter values.

You can read more about this and other parameter related expressions here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/built-in-collections-parameters-collection-references-report-builder?view=sql-server-ver16